# How to call multiple cells in dataframes within a list (R)?

Tags: r, list, indexing, dplyr

I'm struggling with how to index through lists.  My data (as a list of data.frames) is similar to this:

```
x <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(4.2,6.5,9.6, 9.3, 8.1)); names(x) <- c("Time", "Value")
y <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(8.5, 3.7, 5.4, 4.7, 9.2)); names(y) <- c("Time", "Value")
dat <- list(x, y); names(dat) <- c("place1", "place2") 
> dat
$place1
  Time Value
1    1   4.2
2    2   6.5
3    3   9.6
4    4   9.3
5    5   8.1

$place2
  Time Value
1    1   8.5
2    2   3.7
3    3   5.4
4    4   4.7
5    5   9.2
```

Where dat is in the form of the data that I have, except my data actually has 20 places and millions of time points.  The key point I think is that the names of the dataframes match factors I want to reference.

The dataframe that I am trying to build is similar in form to this:

```
df <- data.frame(as.factor(c("place1", "place1", "place2", "place1")), c(1,2,1,5), c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
names(df) <- c("Place", "Time", "Value")
```

The dataframe I'm trying to fill has places and times and some other variables, and I want to import the "Values" from my data in dat.  I tried this, using the dplyr package:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Value = as.vector(t(dat[[Place]][match(Time, dat[[Place]]$Time), "Value"])))
```

but this gives me an error "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: recursive indexing failed at level 3"

I can do this individually if I know which element in the list I want, e.g.

```
> dat[[1]][match(df$Time, dat[[1]]$Time), "Value"]
[1] 4.2 6.5 4.2 8.1
```

But how can I do this if I want to go through multiple elements? Thanks!

Comment: It may be easier to put your list into long format: `l = data.table::rbindlist(dat, idcol=TRUE)`, which would make it easier to match or merge. `l$Value[match(paste(df$Place, df$Time), paste(l$.id, l$Time))]` (Im sure there will be a more `data.table` way, at least, for this second step)

Answer (score 0):

```
df$Value = sapply(1:NROW(df), function(i) dat[[df$Place[i]]][["Value"]][df$Time[i]])
df
#   Place Time Value
#1 place1    1   4.2
#2 place1    2   6.5
#3 place2    1   8.5
#4 place1    5   8.1
```

OR

```
merge(x = df[c("Place", "Time")],
      y = do.call(rbind, lapply(names(dat), function(x) data.frame(Place = x, dat[[x]]))),
      all.x = TRUE)
#   Place Time Value
#1 place1    1   4.2
#2 place1    2   6.5
#3 place1    5   8.1
#4 place2    1   8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(names(dat),function(nm){merge(df[df$Place==nm,setdiff(colnames(df),"Value")],dat[[nm]],by=c("Time"))}))

Time  Place Value
1    1 place1   4.2
2    2 place1   6.5
3    5 place1   8.1
4    1 place2   8.5
```